# Is there any official accreditation a browser or Javascript engine receives from ECMA?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Other than a browser compatibility table, is there any official accreditation a browser or engine receives from ECMA if they meet a certain percentage of compliance of the ECMAScript standards?

Comment: I can't find any official accreditation or list of conforming implementations, other than this note (and others) defining what it means to be a "conforming implementation" -- *A conforming implementation of ECMAScript must provide and support all the types, values, objects, properties, functions, and program syntax and semantics described in this specification.* ( Source: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html )

Comment: There's the [Official ECMAScript Conformance Test Suite](https://github.com/tc39/test262), but I don't think they give out any badges or so.

Comment: Nothing official I'm aware of.  There are third party (unofficial) compatibility tables like this one: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ that I find useful.